# AWS permission for role: AccessDeniedException

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, aws-ssm, aws-roles, aws-permissions

I have an AWS Role with `ReadOnlyAccess` (AWS Managed Policy).

I need to make this role capable of executing some actions, for example **start/stop an Amazon EC2 instance** and **connect via ssm in eu-west-1 and eu-central-1 regions**, but even full permission for EC2 and SSM it does not allow to perform listed actions:

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:*",
                "ssm:*",
                
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:RequestedRegion": [
                        "eu-west-1",
                        "eu-central-1",
                        
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
```

When starting instances it is trying to start (I see it in CloudTrail Logs) but then it stopped in 2 seconds.

For `ssm connect` I received the error:

> An error occurred while calling the StartConnection API operation. AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::acc_id:assumed-role/sre/user is not authorized to perform: ssm-guiconnect:StartConnection on resource: arn:aws:ec2:eu-central-1:acc_id:instance/*"

However, if I add full permissions for this role it works and users with this role may perform needed actions:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:RequestedRegion": [
                        "eu-west-1",
                        "eu-central-1",
                        "us-east-1"
                    ]
                }
            }
```

Is there some bug in AWS or could there be pitfalls from my infrastructure side?

Comment: I used policysim.aws.amazon.com/home/index.jsp#role/sre to debag policy and find out that: 
1. AWS policy do not recognice regions in "condition" 
2. for ssm connection it is needed  "ssm-guiconnect:StartConnection"  and  "ssm:StartSession" permitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS policy do not recognice regions in "condition"
EC2 instances:
I found that encryption is used for EC2 on this account, so full rights for kms(kms:*) solved the problem with instance start.
SSM (Fleet manager): used policysim.aws.amazon.com/home/index.jsp#role/sre to debag policy and find out that:
For ssm connection it is needed "ssm-guiconnect:StartConnection" and "ssm:StartSession" permitions.